# grep not saving all lines

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

Hi someone from the community write this code. The problem is that when I am trying the save the output from grep in my `Positivos.txt` file it only saves the last day and not all the loop. I try using `grep -r -o` but it did not work.

```
d1="2020-03-15"
until [[ "$d1" ==  $ano-$mes-$dia ]]
do
rep=$( date -d "$d1" +%d/%m/%Y )
d1=$( date -I -d "$d1 + 1 day" )
grep -o "$estado.*$rep" /home/efc20/Proyecto/CasosPositivos.csv > Positivos.txt
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` is called several times. Each following call overwrites the output of the earlier one.

1. You can append instead:

   ```
   d1="2020-03-15"
   until [[ "$d1" ==  $ano-$mes-$dia   ]]
   do
   rep=$( date -d "$d1" +%d/%m/%Y )
   d1=$( date -I -d "$d1 + 1 day" )
   grep   -o "$estado.*$rep" /home/efc20/Proyecto/CasosPositivos.csv >> Positivos.txt
   done
   ```
2. You can collect the whole loop's output and write that to the file so that it is only one write (i.e. one opening of the file). There is a certain risk that other parts of the loop (after changing the code) create output which unintentionally gets written to the same file.

   ```
   d1="2020-03-15"
   until [[ "$d1" ==  $ano-$mes-$dia   ]]
   do
   rep=$( date -d "$d1" +%d/%m/%Y )
   d1=$( date -I -d "$d1 + 1 day" )
   grep   -o "$estado.*$rep" /home/efc20/Proyecto/CasosPositivos.csv
   done > Positivos.txt
   ```
3. The most elegant solution (which does not make a practical difference in this case) would be to open a new file descriptor:

   ```
   exec 3>Positivos.txt
   d1="2020-03-15"
   until [[ "$d1" ==  $ano-$mes-$dia   ]]
   do
   rep=$( date -d "$d1" +%d/%m/%Y )
   d1=$( date -I -d "$d1 + 1 day" )
   grep   -o "$estado.*$rep" /home/efc20/Proyecto/CasosPositivos.csv >&3
   done
   ```